# PIVOT on Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a CTE as follows

```
WITH  details
        AS ( SELECT FldId
                   ,Rev
                   ,Words
                   ,row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY FldId ORDER BY Rev DESC ) AS rn
             FROM   WorkItemLongTexts
             WHERE  ID = 2855
           )
  SELECT  f.ReferenceName
         ,d.FldId
         ,Rev
         ,Words
  FROM    details AS d
          INNER JOIN Fields AS f ON f.FldId = d.FldId
  WHERE   d.rn = 1 ;
```

The above returns the following output

```
ReferenceName    |   FldId      |    Rev     |    Words
Description            52            2            Description here  
Objectives           10257           2            Objectives here  
Specification        10258           6            Specification here  
Requirements          10259           6            Requirements here
```

I want to apply PIVOT (or whatever is the best option) so that i can get output as follows

```
Description         |     Objectives     |   Specification      |  Requirements
```

Description here        Objectives here              Specification here             Requirements here

Pls. suggest.

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, Rob Farley's answer is the best, as it is the only one that works for me.  It appears the syntax here is very delicate, almost anything can break it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH  details
        AS ( SELECT FldId
                   ,Rev
                   ,Words
                   ,row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY FldId ORDER BY Rev DESC ) AS rn
             FROM   WorkItemLongTexts
             WHERE  ID = 2855
           ),
      cte_1
        AS ( SELECT f.ReferenceName
                   ,d.FldId
                   ,Rev
                   ,Words
             FROM   details AS d
                    INNER JOIN Fields AS f ON f.FldId = d.FldId
             WHERE  d.rn = 1
           )
  SELECT  max(case [ReferenceName] WHEN 'Descripton' THEN [Words] ELSE NULL END) AS [Descripton]
         ,max(case [ReferenceName] WHEN 'Objectives' THEN [Words] ELSE NULL END) AS [Objectives]
         ,max(case [ReferenceName] WHEN 'Specification' THEN [Words] ELSE NULL END) AS [Specification]
         ,max(case [ReferenceName] WHEN 'Requirements' THEN [Words] ELSE NULL END) AS [Requirements]
  FROM    cte_1 ;
```

**OR**:

```
  -- cte here as above
  SELECT  Description
         ,Objectives
         ,Specification
         ,Requirements
  FROM    cte_1 PIVOT ( max(Words) FOR ReferenceName IN ( Description,
                                                          Objectives,
                                                          Specification,
                                                          Requirements ) ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: getting error "Operand data type ntext is invalid for max operator."

Comment: Can you cast to nvarchar(max)? ntext is deprecated.

Comment: `...THEN CAST([Words] AS nvarchar(max)`) instead of `THEN [Words]`; or nvarchar(4000) if 4000 is enough

Comment: OR inside cte_1 SELECT; `CAST([Words] AS nvarchar(max))`

Answer (score 7):

You do this:

```
SELECT
    FldId,
    [Description],
    [Objectives],
    [Specification],
    [Requirements]
FROM (
    SELECT
        ReferenceName,
        FldId,
        REV,
        Words
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RowNumber = 1
) t
PIVOT (
    MIN(Words)
    FOR ReferenceName IN ([Description], [Objectives], [Specification], [Requirements])
) PIV
```

Or you can add it to your CTE, like this:

```
;WITH CTE2 AS (
    SELECT
        FldId,
        REV,
        [Description],
        [Objectives],
        [Specification],
        [Requirements],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FldId ORDER BY REV DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM TBL
PIVOT (
        MIN(Words)
        FOR ReferenceName IN ([Description], [Objectives], [Specification], [Requirements])
    ) PIV
)

SELECT
    FldId,
    REV,
    [Description],
    [Objectives],
    [Specification],
    [Requirements]
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Do something like:

```
with details as (...)
, unpivotted as (select f.ReferenceName, Words 
  from details as d
  inner join Fields as f
  on f.FldId=d.FldId
  where d.rn =1)
Select *
from unpivotted 
pivot 
(max(Words) for Description in ([Objectives],[Specification],[Requirements]) p
;
```

Comment: I have tried many of these from various posts on the web.  This is the ONLY one that worked for me.  It looks like in selecting from unpivotted it picks up the pivoted fields also, so maybe that should be given a more generic name like 'OurQuery' ... still wonderful job!!!

Comment: @JosephDoggie The hassle is the way that pivot implies that any column not in the aggregate part of the pivot clause must be part of the group by. By planning the unpivotted version first (without any extra columns), you have a much cleaner result.