# converting ID to column name and also replacing NULL with last known value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**TABLE_A**

```
Rev     ChangedBy
-----------------------------
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

**TABLE_B**

```
Rev Words      ID
----------------------------
1 description_1   52
1 history_1         54
2 description_2   52
3 history_2         54
```

Words column datatype is ntext.

**TABLE_C**

```
ID Name
-----------------------------
52 Description
54 History
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Rev ChangedBy Description        History  
------------------------------------------------
1     A   description_1      history_1
2     B   description_2      history_1
3     C   description_2      history_2
```

Description and History column will have the previous known values if they dont have value for that Rev no. i.e. Since for Rev no. 3 Description does not have an entry in TABLE_B hence the last known value description_2 appears in that column for Rev no. 3 in the output.

Comment: This looks like fairly straight forward joins to me.  What query have you tried and what is not working about it?

Comment: Why does Rev 3 list "description_2" rather than "history_2" in the output?  Otherwise, it looks like a join between tables A and B on the rev value...

Comment: because description column will not have history values. Since Rev 3 does not have any entry related to description in Table_B hence it is showing the last known value which is description_2. I hope i was able to explain.

Comment: @BoltBait: I have just started with T-SQL and not sure how to convert the ID field to column name (probably UNPIVOT) and populating NULL with last known value from Table_B.

Comment: @BoltBait: I tried the following:

select a.Rev, a.ChangedBy, b.Words,c.Name from Table_A as a
inner join Table_B as b on a.Rev = b.Rev
inner join Table_C as c on b.FId = c.Id

But this is not the desired result.

Comment: How on earth do you get "description_2" for rev = 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from following posts
[PIVOT on Common Table Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949372/pivot-on-common-table-expression)
[SQL QUERY replace NULL value in a row with a value from the previous known value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345065/sql-query-replace-null-value-in-a-row-with-a-value-from-the-previous-known-value)

I was able to come up with following query to get the desired output.

```
    ;WITH CTE_A AS
    (
        SELECT a.Rev, a.ChangedBy, CAST(b.Words as nvarchar(max)) as [Words],c.Name FROM Table_A AS a
        INNER JOIN Table_B AS b ON a.Rev = b.Rev
        INNER JOIN Table_C AS c ON b.FId = c.Id
    ),
    CTE_B AS
    (

    select Rev, ChangedBy, [Description], [History] from
    CTE_A
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([Words])
        FOR [Name] in ([Description],[History])
    ) as p
    )

select Rev,ChangedBy, 
ISNULL([Description],(select top 1 [Description] from CTE_B where Rev < t.Rev and [Description] is not null order by Rev desc)),
ISNULL([History],(select top 1 [History] from CTE_B where Rev < t.Rev and [History] is not null order by Rev desc))  
from CTE_B t
```